# Page reloading before it know the post has been deleted?

Tags: php, post

I have a class that contains 2 functions one for removing post and one for submitting post. The function for submitting the post will redirect to any page I want just fine and if it is the same page it will be displayed with the new post.

The function used for removing the post will refresh or redirect but if it's redirected back to the same page the page does not appear updated until the page is refreshed again (a second time). I have looked and haven't found anything that works or a reason why this is happening. I'm new to php so go easy on me!

Is the page reloading before it know the post has been deleted? What can I do to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
class userPost{
     // For Removing Post 
function remove(){
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") && ($_POST['delete_id'])){

    if(!$_POST['delete_id'] || !$_SESSION['SESS_USER']){
            header('Location: ?id=profile');
    }
    else{
$delete = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
$remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Post WHERE post_id = '".$delete."' AND   post_member='" . $_SESSION['SESS_USER'] . "'");   
        if($remove){ 
            header('Location: ?id=profile');    
        }
        elseif(!$remove){ ?>
        <script>
        $('#div-id').triggerevent(function(){
  $('#div-id').html(newContent);
});
</script>
        <?php
        } // End Else
        } // End Else
        } // End If
   } // End If
} // End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `exit;` after `header`. Otherwise PHP continues to process the script.

**As an aside:** Don't continue programming this way. There are so many issues with this script I wouldn't know where to start. A good book to learn PHP the right way is [PHP : Ojects, Patterns, and Practices](http://www.apress.com/9781430229254/) by Matt Zandstra.

Comment: that kinda works only it refreshs the page and display the post being deleted and nothing else below until i refresh again. Should i change the conditional statement to not check for values first?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, like I said im new to php and trying to learn as much as I can. I will be sure to check out the book.

Comment: Yeah, Google the ISBN number. You can usually find a cheap used copy on Amazon or eBay.

Comment: Thats what I just did, Amazon has one for $15 used so im gonna buy it.